# Переносы в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
'/<\?if\((.*?)\)\?>(.*?)<\?endif\?>/'
```

Однако оно срабатывает только, если написать например так:

```
<?if(5+1 > 7)?>123<?endif?>
```

А нужно, чтобы работали и переносы строк, например:

```
<?if(5+1 > 7)?>
123
<?endif?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'/<\?if\((.*?)\)\?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\?endif\?>/'
```

[>пример<](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/%3C%5C%3Fif%5C((.*%3F)%5C)%5C%3F%3E%5Cs*(.*%3F)%5Cs*%3C%5C%3Fendif%5C%3F%3E%40%3D%23%3D%40101%40%3D%23%3D%40%3C%3Fif(5%2B1%20%3E%207)%3F%3E%262a%3B123%262a%3B%3C%3Fendif%3F%3E%262a%3B/)

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется в данном случае лучше использовать [модификатор **s**](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) к регулярному выражению, а к группам с результатом применять [trim](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php).
В таком примере данный подход даст искомый результат не изменяя само регулярное выражение.

```
<?if(5+1 > 7)?>
multiline
string
<?endif?>
```

Comment: Сорри за некропост :) Просматривал вопросы с меткой регулярные выражения, а он оказывается месячной давности.